# Xpath Matching a node and getting the value of it

Tags: xslt, xpath

0. Below is the xml file:

file1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><W4N xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"><LUNGROUP><OBJECT lungroupID="0" lunIds="0,221,228"/></LUNGROUP><LUNGROUP><OBJECT lungroupID="1" lunIds="1,3,5/></LUNGROUP></W4N>
```

I want to match  on lunIds. I have given the below xpath expression /W4N/LUNGROUP/OBJECT[tokenize(@lunIds,',')='228']
Its showing the result as Elements found: 1
Now my requirement is to get the lungroupID of the matched element.How can I do this using xpath? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `/W4N/LUNGROUP/OBJECT[tokenize(@lunIds,',')='228']/@lungroupID`

Comment: One more thing if I want to get the lungroupID comma separated if multiple value matches.What change do I need to do?

Comment: @Barun If you are using the `xsl:value-of` instruction with the above expression, you will get a space-separated list of the selected values. You can use the `translate()` function to convert the spaces to commas.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the XML you intended to post, but you should be able to add the attribute you want at the end of your xpath expression:

/W4N/LUNGROUP/OBJECT[tokenize(@lunIds,',')='228']/@lungroupID

Comment: One more thing if I want to get the lungroupID comma separated if multiple value matches.What change do I need to do? Below is the xml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><W4N xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"><LUNGROUP><OBJECT lungroupID="0" lunIds="0,221,228"/></LUNGROUP><LUNGROUP><OBJECT lungroupID="1" lunIds="1,3,5,221"/></LUNGROUP></W4N>

Comment: You can select the attribute value using this expression: //*/@lungroupID

As for comma-separated, that depends on what language you are coding in.

Comment: @Barun, the use of `tokenize` suggests you use XPath 2 or later so for a comma separated result you can also use the `string-join` function in e.g. `string-join(/W4N/LUNGROUP/OBJECT[tokenize(@lunIds,',')='228']/@lungroupID, ',')`.